# Wordpress Shortcodes for Displaying subsets of events

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I understand there is a shortcode for displaying a list of upcoming events, that is

[civievent_widget]

Is there a way to display categories of events as shown below?

http://www.torontodance.com/events/categories/salsa/

Also are there ways to filter events by location and other filters?   If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The shortcode you refer to is provided by the [CiviEvent Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civievent-widget/) plugin. It has a number of configuration options which you can read about on the plugin homepage. I would look at the `custom_filter` options to see if you can make it fit your requirements.

If the widget doesn't allow filtering by event category, I'd consider a more complex (but also more flexible) system based on [Event Organiser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/) and [CiviCRM Event Organiser](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser) which will definitely do what you're after.

Have a look at the [standard calendar](http://spirit-of-football.de/kalender/), an [event category](http://spirit-of-football.de/events/kategorien/schulische-angebote/) and the [list of events at a venue](http://spirit-of-football.de/events/orte/kunstrasen-am-nordpark/) for the kind of things that are available out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Christian is correct.  You can do this using the "Custom" tab of the CiviEvent Widget.  Use a JSON code in the "Custom API filter" field like this:

{"event_type_id": 7}

Where "7" is the id of the event type you want.

You can even use a range of type ids like this:

{"event_type_id": {">=": 7}}